# Swift Errors with syntax

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

Can someone help me fix these errors? Swift changed and I don't know how to change these to make it work with the new version:

This one gives the following error:

> Cannot invoke createDirectoryAtPath with an argument list of type (SwiftCoreDataHelper.Type, withintermediateDirectories: Bool, atrributes: NilLiteralConvertible, error:inout NSError?)

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)
```

The next couple just give me that 'error' is an extra argument:

```
if storeCoordicator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error){
        if (error != nil){
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            abort()
        }
    }

let items: NSArray = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2, you need to catch the error with `do-catch` block;
when using `addPersistentStoreWithType` with CoreData, you would need to do the following:

```
do
{
    try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
}
catch(let error as NSError)
{
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription) //error has occurred.
    abort() //abort
}
```

The same is applied for `executeFetchRequest`:

```
do
{
    let items: NSArray = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
}
catch(let error as NSError)
{
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

As with `createDirectoryAtPath`:

```
do
{
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
catch(let error as NSError)
{
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you that fixed those two but how do I go about fixing the             NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)